# No Wireless on Ubuntu 15.10 with Broadcom 4350 Card

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom

I have the New XPS13 Skylake laptop, which has DW1820A or Broadcom 4350 Wireless card.

I was following the instructions from https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/467270, I did

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

But, still no luck on getting wireless from on this device.

As part of the instruction said, I am asking a new question to post the new PCI ID:

```
[14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
```

Community, please help.

Comment: According to this: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211 the device 14e4:43a3 is to be supported in kernel version 4.4 by the driver `brcmfmac`. In Ubuntu 15.10, using 4.2.0-xx, it is not yet supported. Sorry.

Comment: I was able to get the wireless working on Arch Linux - someone provided a version 4.3 Linux kernel with the 4350 driver backported to it. Additionally new linux-firmware is needed. I have been unable to find similar resources for Ubuntu aside from compiling them manually.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get wireless working by upgrading to version 4.4 of the kernel, as chili555 mentioned. As I'm writing, the Ubuntu team is at release candidate 8 of the 4.4 kernel.

To install the newer kernel version, first install Ubuntu (I used 15.10), then download the most recent Ubuntu build from the [Ubuntu kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), move the appropriate `.deb` files on a USB drive to your laptop, and install them with `dpkg -i *.deb`.

I used v4.4-rc8-wily, but newer versions are released all the time.
See [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/142000) for general guidance on upgrading to a newer kernel version.

After restarting, I installed the newest versions of the `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` packages I could find.  You can find them by searching online for 'ubuntu packages linux-firmware' and 'ubuntu packages linux-firmware-nonfree'.
(I apologize for not posting direct links; apparently I need more reputation points to have more than two URLs.)

Answer (score 0):

Replacement of the wifi card in the Skylake XPS 13 currently appears to be the best option since the included bcm4350 card, since there does not appear to be any drivers available yet. The form factor for the wifi card on the Skylake XPS 13 is m.2 ngff not half mini PCIe. The Intel 7265 card is working with Ubuntu 15.10, out of the box.