# No Wireless with broadcom BCM4350 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, dell, broadcom

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an Dell XPS 13 9350 (skylake)

Since the old kernel doesn't support the broadcom wireless card I updated to ubuntu 16.04, coming from 15.10. The 4.4 kernel should support the card. But it still doesn't work.

EDIT: It seems that only starting from the 4.4.1-1 kernel the broadcom wireless card is supported ([see Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_%282016%29#Wireless)).

So, iwconfig shows the card. Also lspci shows it.

If I type `sudo ip link set mywlan up` ubuntu activates the card, but somehow recognizes it as an ethernet card. If I click the network Icon on the top right it says "Ethernet Network (Broadcom BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter)". And of course I don't get a connection to any wireless network. So... Any hints on how to change that? Any Ideas?

Greetings

this question is related to [No Wireless on Ubuntu 15.10 with Broadcom 4350 Card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692452/no-wireless-on-ubuntu-15-10-with-broadcom-4350-card)

EDIT:
Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0021]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

Looks like the right driver is in use...

File properties of brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin:

```
freebe@ubun:~$ ls -al /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 626140 Mär 21 13:27 /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
```

EDIT (summary): So even with the 4.4.1 kernel ubuntu sometimes recognizes the card as a wifi-card, but most of the time as an ethernet card. For me it actually only recognized the card as a wifi-card once(!), this was at the first boot. This is probably a bug. If anyone has a reliable way to solve this issue I would be very thankful!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: has been done :)

Comment: Does `/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin` exist in your system?

Comment: Yes it, does exist, I added the file properties to the Main post

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was very simple. I should have read the [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692452/no-wireless-on-ubuntu-15-10-with-broadcom-4350-card) I already linked to in the main post more thoroughly!

I just went to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.1-wily/
downloaded the kernel image for 64bit systems (.deb-file) and installed it by double-clicking (Ubuntu Software Center). WiFi works now! :))

Thats it... Mui simple, very simple

EDIT: No, not that simple... see main thread -.-

Answer (score 0):

For me it almost always works with `4.4.0-12-generic`, for all the more recent kernel versions it only occasionally works but most of the time the wireless adapter is recognized as an ethernet card and does not work.

Comment: Which repositories do I have to add into /etc/apt/sources.list to get this kernel version? I'm currently using 4.4.0-22

Comment: It's just there from left from the first beta version of 16.04 that I tried, with `apt autoremove` it would be removed. I don't know how to install an outdated package. Would be curios if things works with a mainline newer kernel. I recently tried yakkety with 4.5 kernel and it worked there (but it might just have been chance as I booted only once).

Comment: According to the arch.wiki [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_13_%282016%29#Wireless) it works starting from kernel 4.4.1-1. Thats probably also the kernel I used when I was using Arch. Which brings me to the next question: How do I install a different kernel in general?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work even with the latest 4.6 RC. I've created https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119321

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug. Although I doubt it is a kernel related bug, because it worked fine when I was using Arch Linux... Anyway, thanks for filing it!

Comment: Just found out that suspending (pm-suspend) gives you a new chance, so if its not working it might work after suspend, unfortunately the converse is also true.